# What does "roots" mean in "Find the roots of $f(x)=-1$" or "Prove that $f(x)=-1$ has no roots if $x > 0$"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology, roots

I know that the roots of a function mean the $x$-coordinate of the points whose $y$-coordinate is equal to zero, or the $x$-coordinates where the function cuts the $x$-axis.

So when I am faced by questions like this:

> $f(x) = \frac16x+5$, find the roots of the equation $f(x)= -1$

or

> Prove that $f(x)=-1$ has no roots if $x > 0$.

I got truely confused, because all the answers we'll get from solving will have nothing to do with the roots of the actual function. What I'll get will just be the $x$-coordinate when I substitute the $y$ by -1 in the function $f(x)$.

Could he mean the roots of the **new equation** I'll get when I move the $-1$ to the left side and make the new equation equal to zero ($\frac16x+5\color{red}{+1}=0$), or does he mean the roots of the **vertical line** ($x= -1$) I'll get when I solve the equation?

Or is actually whatever perceptive I look from right and no one is better than another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)=-1$ gives you a simple equation in $x$ which you can solve for $x$ by any method you choose (just take care that you are not dividing by zero).

For the second, if $x\gt 0$ can $f(x)=-1$? (Consider the sign of $f(x)$ for example).

A root in this context is a value of $x$ for which the equation is satisfied. Can you find a root (Q1), or can you constrain a root by showing that some set of numbers cannot be roots (Q2).

Comment: In Q1 x= -1 and in Q2 -1 is smaller than zero. But does this mean that the word roots here have no real graphical meaning?

Comment: @Manar One point of view is that the roots here are any points where $y=f(x)$ crosses the line $y=-1$ [There is only one root in the case you have quoted]. Equivalently you could say that the roots are where the graph of $y=f(x)+1$ crosses the $x-$ axis.

Comment: I imagined this too! But what about the view that it's the root of the vertical line x=-1, is this a wrong perspective?

Comment: @Manar: That is not what is generally meant by that.  Unless it is stated explicitly, I would assume that it means "solutions to the given equation"—usually zeros, but not always, as in this case.

Comment: @Manar $x=-1$ is a solution, of course, but it is a derived fact, not one given as part of the initial problem. I would suggest that the graphical perspective most useful to the solution is the one which depends on the given data and from which the solution is derived. The line $x=-1$ becomes relevant only when the solution $x=-1$ is known.